# Connect Laravel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, database-connection

Hi I have been trying to connect for two days actually I need to connect to SQL SERVER from my Laravel project. I have installed all the required drivers

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
```

and I added them in the folder ext of php 8.0.25

I also installed `msodbcsql.msi` (Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server)

But I still get this error...???

> POST http://localhost/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

I connect in Windows Authentication mode to the sql server
will I need to provide a DB_USERNAME ?

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=ecommerce
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

database.php

```
  'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

Comment: you should tell the error message, check your error log or just enable debug mode

Comment: i got this : {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 08001): SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be established because the target computer has expressly refused it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after

**my problem was in .env file**

#### Solution

##### with : ***windows authentification***

```bash
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=your_server_name ### example: xxx\xxx 

DB_PORT=null

DB_DATABASE=ecommerce

DB_USERNAME=

DB_PASSWORD=
```

##### with : ***sql server authentification***

```bash
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv

DB_HOST=your_server_name ###  example: xxx\xxx

DB_PORT=null

DB_DATABASE=ecommerce

DB_USERNAME=sa

DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```